# Iterations over 2d numpy arrays with while and for statements

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

In the code supplied below I am trying to iterate over 2D numpy array [i][k]
Originally it is a code which was written in Fortran 77 which is older than my grandfather. I am trying to adapt it to python.
(for people interested whatabouts: it is a simple hydraulics transients event solver)
Bear in mind that all variables are introduced in my code which I don't paste here.

```
  H = np.zeros((NS,50))
  Q = np.zeros((NS,50))
```

Here I am assigning the first row values:

```
    for i in range(NS):
       H[0][i] = HR-i*R*Q0**2
       Q[0][i] = Q0

 CVP = .5*Q0**2/H[N]
 T = 0
 k = 0
 TAU = 1
 #Interior points:
 HP = np.zeros((NS,50))
 QP = np.zeros((NS,50))

 while T<=Tmax:
     T += dt
     k += 1
     for i in range(1,N):
         CP = H[k][i-1]+Q[k][i-1]*(B-R*abs(Q[k][i-1]))
         CM = H[k][i+1]-Q[k][i+1]*(B-R*abs(Q[k][i+1]))
         HP[k][i-1] = 0.5*(CP+CM)
         QP[k][i-1] = (HP[k][i-1]-CM)/B
 #Boundary Conditions:
 HP[k][0] = HR
 QP[k][0] = Q[k][1]+(HP[k][0]-H[k][1]-R*Q[k][1]*abs(Q[k][1]))/B
     if T == Tc:
         TAU = 0
         CV = 0
     else:
         TAU = (1.-T/Tc)**Em
         CV = CVP*TAU**2
     CP = H[k][N-1]+Q[k][N-1]*(B-R*abs(Q[k][N-1]))
     QP[k][N] = -CV*B+np.sqrt(CV**2*(B**2)+2*CV*CP)
     HP[k][N] = CP-B*QP[k][N]
     for i in range(NS):
         H[k][i] = HP[k][i]
         Q[k][i] = QP[k][i]
```

Remember `i` is for rows and `k` is for columns
What I am expecting is that for all k number of columns the values should be calculated until T<=Tmax condition is met. I cannot figure out what my mistake is, I am getting the following errors:

```
 RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
 CVP = .5*Q0**2/H[N]

 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
 QP[N][k] = -CV*B+np.sqrt(CV**2*(B**2)+2*CV*CP)

 QP[N][k] = -CV*B+np.sqrt(CV**2*(B**2)+2*CV*CP)
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What is B? And which are the dimensions of it?

Comment: If you read statement I said that all variables are introduced in my code and I didn’t type them here. Think of them as constants

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your first iteration:

```
H = np.zeros((NS,50))
Q = np.zeros((NS,50))
for i in range(NS):
   H[0][i] = HR-i*R*Q0**2
   Q[0][i] = Q0
```

The shape of `H` is `(NS,50)`, but when you iterate over a `range(NS)` you apply that index to the 2nd dimension.  Why?  Shouldn't it apply to the dimension with size `NS`?

In `numpy` arrays have 'C' order by default.  Last dimension is inner most.  They can have a `F` (fortran) order, but let's not go there.  Thinking of the 2d array as a table, we typically talk of rows and columns, though they don't have a formal definition in `numpy`.

Lets assume you want to set the first column to these values:

```
for i in range(NS):
    H[i, 0] = HR - i*R*Q0**2
    Q[i, 0] = Q0
```

But we can do the assignment whole rows or columns at a time.  I believe new versions of Fortran also have these 'whole-array' functions.

```
Q[:, 0] = Q0  
H[:, 0] = HR - np.arange(NS) * R * Q0**2
```

One point of caution when translating to `Python`.  Indexing starts with 0; so does ranges and `np.arange(...)`.

`H[0][i]` is functionally the same as `H[0,i]`.  But when using slices you have to use the `H[:,i]` format.

I suspect your other iterations have similar problems, but I'll stop here for now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the errors:

- The first:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
 CVP = .5*Q0**2/H[N]
```

You initialize H as zeros so it is normal that it complains of division by zero. Maybe you should add a conditional.

- The third:

```
 QP[N][k] = -CV*B+np.sqrt(CV**2*(B**2)+2*CV*CP)
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

You define `CVP = .5*Q0**2/H[N]`  and then `CV = CVP*TAU**2` which is a sequence. And then you try to assign a derivate form it to `QP[N][K]` which is an element. You are trying to insert an array to a value.

- For the second error I think it might be related to the third. If you could provide more information I would like to try to understand what happens.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the comment.
The Q0 is not an array, it is just a value calculated in my code. I cannot find a way to show all the code to you. I dont want to edit my original post because I dont want the reader to get confused in reading the question

Comment: I am really sorry, you are right about CVP. The H[N] there should be H[0][N]. After doing I dont get RunTimeErrors. Thanks again

Comment: Please, if the answer has been useful, could you mark it as accepted. If you consider so obviously.

Comment: It’s been useful but doesn’t answer the question. Sorry for that